# Dropdownlist SelectedIndexChanged event in javascript with asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have an 2 dropdownlist for each row in aspx page using JavaScript( multiple entry like grid) , my prob is i don't know how to load the data's in dropdownlist2 based on choosing dropdownlist1, sorry I'm new for JavaScript

if you want my sample page means i'll upload , and am using visual studio 2010 c#

Thanks in advance.

Edit

### C# for loading data in load event for dropdownlist1

protected void fnaddproduct()
    {

```
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ClsConn.DbConn))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Exec Usp_Product_Load", conn);
        conn.Open();
        rea = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rea.Read())
        {
            ddlproductname_1.Items.Add(new ListItem(rea.GetString(1), rea.GetValue(0).ToString()));                
        }
        rea.Close();
    }
}
```

now based(ddlproductname_1) i.e product name   i need to load product(each product has many size) size in dropdownlist2( using javascript) because this multiple entry.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show what you have done so far?

Answer (score 0):

The following demos could be helpful to achieve your scenario:
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/dropdownlist/examples/applicationscenarios/cascadingdropdownlists/defaultcs.aspx
and 
http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/multiplecomboboxes/defaultcs.aspx